# In C#, what is the difference between a list and IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

How does a list differ from an IEnumerable in C#. Specifically, in what kind of circumstances would you use one over the other? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

Currently, I have been using lists and IEnumerables interchangeably but I would like to better understand the uses of both.

Comment: IEnumerable is a basic interface that might be a List, or might be an array, or might be an iterator block, or might be a custom object, or might be...  You use it so to make the code more adaptable for different possibilities down the road. You also use it avoid needing to allocate new buffers for lists (ie: calling ToList() ), and it can be used in some situations to only need one item in memory at all (instead of the whole collection). You should prefer IEnumerable over List in most situations where it's actually an option.

Comment: [continued] On the other had, you would use a `List()` if you need `[]` indexer access or other features not provided by IEnumerable, such as the ability to more easily add new items to a set over time. There are also times where having a list that actually forces everything in memory all at once can be advantage. For example, loading lines _once_ from a file, instead of repeating the file I/O for every access to a value.